# Compare Data in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have an excel spreadsheet with 8 columns. I need to compare multiple columns and rows, can this be done in Excel?

I need to:

1. Compare values in column A and find matches
2. If duplicates in column A, compare values in Column B to make sure they are not duplicates.
3. Then compare value in column F in row 1 to value in column D in row 2 to see if they are with 1 day (both columns contain dates).

Is this too complicated for Excel?

Comment: It's all perfectly possible in Excel, though you may need to use VBA. I would do some of it for you, but you have not been 100% clear. Here are some things you need to clear up: 1. When you say compare values in Column A to find matches (duplicates), what do you want to compare the values to? Each other (the entirety of column A)? 2. You say "if duplicates in column A, compare values in column B...", but do you want to compare the value that was the duplicate? Do you want to search the entire column B for the duplicate (or for ANY duplicate?) or just the specific row of the duplicated item? 3.

Comment: Adding some sample data would be very helpful since this is pretty complex, but Excel should be able to do it.